# Github fatal: bad config line 3 in file /home/dru7/.gitconfig

Tags: git

I do not understand why I cannot configure .gitconfig in Debian shell.

Look at the screen attached.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried to add correct username and email based on GitHub registration, but the shell keeps returning:

```
fatal: bad config line 3 in file /home/dru7/.gitconfig
```

I have deleted the hashes in config file and still the same.

What am I doing wrong? Why is not working?

Comment: We can't see line 3 (or any of the lines at all, really) of your `.gitconfig` file because your screenshot shows only the window in which you've typed various commands, not the window in which the file contents were displayed. To fix that, (1) don't use screenshots at all (see [ask]) and (2) cut and paste the *file's* text as needed. Use code blocks (intended or backquoted) to show computer text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If depends on what is in `/home/dru7/.gitconfig`, but I would check:

- the error persists on `git config --global -l`
- if removing / simplifying the content of the file helps

As long as `git config --global -l` returns an error, keep removing lines around line 3, until you get to the one which was the culprit.